# How would I use a dictionary for mapping in Hive?

Tags: sql, dictionary, hive, hiveql

Let's assume I have a table 'my_table':

```
region_code | name
123         | 'test'
54          | 'test2'
```

and a dictionary:

```
dict = (123 -> "Moscow", 54 -> "Saint Petersburg")
```

I want to do:

`select dict[region_code] as region_code, name from my_table` to get:

```
region_code       | name
'Moscow'          | 'test'
'Saint Petersburg'| 'test2'
```

Is this possible in hive?

Answer (score 0):

Dict is a map, you can create map using map() construct and use in the query.

Demo:

```
with my_table as(--demo dataset, use real table instead
select 123 region_code, 'test' name union all
select 54,'test2'
)

select region_code,
       map(123, "Moscow", 54, "Saint Petersburg")[region_code] as region_name,
       name
  from my_table;
```

Result:

```
region_code region_name         name
123         Moscow              test
54          Saint Petersburg    test2
```

Also if you are using dict multiple times you can use variable:

```
--declare variable
set hiveconf:region_code_name_map=map(123, "Moscow", 54, "Saint Petersburg");

with my_table as(
select 123 region_code, 'test' name union all
select 54,'test2'
)

select region_code,
       --use variable substitution
       ${hiveconf:region_code_name_map}[region_code] as region_name,
       name
  from my_table;
```

Or using macro + variable:

```
--declare variable
set hiveconf:region_code_name_map=map(123, "Moscow", 54, "Saint Petersburg");
--create a macro
create temporary macro code2name(code int) ${hiveconf:region_code_name_map}[code];

with my_table as(
select 123 region_code, 'test' name union all
select 54,'test2'
)

select region_code,
       --use macro
       code2name(region_code) as region_name,
       name
  from my_table
```

All this demo examples produce the same result. Also only map contents can be parametrized: `123, "Moscow", 54, "Saint Petersburg"` and you can put variable inside map() construct in the query.